# Paynet Openpay PHP ¿Como recibo la notificacion de que un pago fue realizado en tienda?

Tags: json, post, openpay, webhook

Estoy creando una aplicación web con openpay para pago en tiendas.

- Ya cree el recibo con el código de barras.
- Ya tengo un webhook verificado en mi dashboard.

Ahora estoy simulando los pagos en tiendas y según tengo entendido el arreglo json se envía a la url de mi webhook para recibirlo. Pero, utilizando:

```
 $request = @file_get_contents('php://input');
  header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

o

```
 $content    =   file_get_contents("php://input");
echo $respuesta  =   json_encode($content);
```

Solo obtengo un `""` de respuesta y no el contenido del JSON que se supone debo recibir.

Lo que intento hacer es que, al simular el pago en el dashboard de openpay, verificar si se me envió la información haciendo refresh en la url de mi webhook (desde mi servidor) para después crear una cuenta en mi base de datos.

No logro obtener la información. No se si es la forma correcta de recibir la notificación.
Esta es la url de la documentación de openpay: https://www.openpay.mx/docs/webhooks.html
x

Comment: pudiste resolverlo?, yo he intentado y definitivamente se que esta mal, tengo el mismo codigo que tu y simplemente tengo semanas tratando y nada, entonces tal vez tu ya tienes la respuesta, me ayudarias mucho

Answer (score 0):

Es decodificar el json:

```
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true);
```

Comment: Acabo de utilizar esa linea que me pusiste y e visto que se llega a esa solución. Pero nos se si mi error es el momento en el que quiero leer la respuesta de open pay. 
Es decir, voy a openpay > paynet > pagos, selecciono un pago y elijo simular pago. Cuando veo el mensaje de confirmación hago un refresh de mi url y me sigue mostrando un NULL ... no se que estoy haciendo mal y no veo mucha documentación o información acerca de la implementación de openpay

Answer (score 0):

El problema de tu código es que estas codificando a JSON un JSON. Como bien te comentaron en lugar de poner `echo $respuesta  =   json_encode($content);` Deberías de tener `$respuesta = json_decode($content)`